# Python sql statement to postgres encoding fail

Tags: python, json, postgresql

I have the following problem that when I try to execute this code:

```
try:
with open('moviedata.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
    for movie in data:
        global year
        global title
        global info
        global directors
        global release
        global rating
        global genres
        global img
        global plot
        global rank
        global running_time
        global actors
        if 'year' in movie:
            year = movie['year']
        if 'title' in movie:
            title = movie['title']
        if 'info' in movie:
            info = movie['info']
        if 'directors' in movie['info']:
            directors = [movie['info']['directors']]
        if 'release_data' in movie:
            release = movie['info']['release_date']
        if 'rating' in movie['info']:
            rating = movie['info']['rating']
        if 'genres' in movie['info']:
            genres = movie['info']['genres']
        if 'image_url' in movie['info']:
            img = movie['info']['image_url']
        if 'plot' in movie['info']:
            plot = movie['info']['plot']
        if 'rank' in movie['info']:
            rank = movie['info']['rank']
        if 'running_time_secs' in movie['info']:
            running_time = movie['info']['running_time_secs']
        if 'actors' in movie['info']:
            actors = movie['info']['actors']
        sqlstatement = '''insert into directors(name)(select %(directors) where not exists(select 1 from directors where name = %(directors));'''
        print sqlstatement
        cur.execute(sqlstatement)
```

The files is a lot of json data on more than 4000 movies and some includes the values you can see in the if statements and some doesn't.

The directors variable does load some data of type string.

Comment: `sqlstatement` is a tuple. It should be a string.

Comment: I see can you give an example on how I convert it?

Comment: Delete `, (directors[0])` from the end of the line.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you should really try to get rid of those `global` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sqlstatement = '''
    insert into directors (name)
    select %(director)s
    where not exists (
        select 1 
        from directors 
        where name = %(director)s
    );
'''
cur.execute(sqlstatement, {'director': directors[0]})
```